# Sendmail not working on ubuntu guest - unqualified host name

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, hosts, sendmail

I have a win7 host running ubuntu guest through vbox. it is configured with a bridged network adapter and I am using DHCP to assign an ip of 192.168.0.5 which is mapped to smartstart.dev in my windows hosts file. I havent done anything to hosts on the ubuntu side.

I am testing a website and need sendmail working. I have installed sendmail, but the mails aren't being sent. When i look through the mail error logs I can see lots of lines like this:

```
Jan 14 17:00:01 djw-ss sm-msp-queue[2771]: My unqualified host name (djw-ss) unknown; sleeping for retry
Jan 14 17:01:02 djw-ss sm-msp-queue[2771]: unable to qualify my own domain name (djw-ss) -- using short name
```

Can anyone tell me how to get this working? Strange thing is I have a similar setup on another vb - I dont think I've done anything different and it works just fine out of the box.